# Cartesian macros on type fields in Julia

Tags: macros, julia

The `Base.Cartesian` module offers the `@nref` macro:

```
using Base.Cartesian
i_1, i_2 = 1, 1
A = rand(3,3)
@nref 2 A i
```

This returns `A[1,1]`. However, `@nref` does not work with fields of a (custom) type:

```
type Foo
    bar::Matrix
end

foo = Foo( rand(3,3) )

i_1, i_2 = 1, 1
@nref 2 foo.bar i
```

This results in an error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `_nref` has no method matching _nref(::Int64, ::Expr, ::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  _nref(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::Any)
```

The error seems reasonable as `foo.bar` is really the expression `getfield(foo, bar)`.
Wrapping the `@nref` in a function and passing `foo.bar` works:

```
function baz(A)
i_1, i_2 = 1, 1
@nref 2 A i
end

baz(foo.bar)
```

But is there a way to make `@nref 2 foo.bar i` work?

Comment: It was the copying I was worried about with `TT = foo.bar`, but `@time` agrees with you about the optimizer. Thanks a lot!
I'd be happy mark the question as answered, but is that possible with only a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign `foo.bar` to a variable, like `TT = foo.bar`, then `@nref 2 TT i` works. This is basically free, as no copy is made, and inside a function optimization makes `TT` identical to `foo.bar`.